# getting wordpress pages according to header menu order

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, single-page-application

I want to query the pages in the order of header menu but I am not getting the proper order. I have tried a couple of combinations but none worked.

Here is one

```
$currentID = get_the_ID();

                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                $args = array('post_type' => 'page',
                              'status' => 'publish',
                              'exclude'=> $currentID,
                              'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                              'sort_column'=>'menu_order',
                              'sort_order' => 'ASC'
                           );

                $pages = get_posts($args);

                return $pages;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394251/wp-nav-menu-find-next-previous-links

Comment: @DavidAlsbright Thanks, i had it confused with menu order of the header. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'orderby' => 'menu_order'` will order the posts as they appear on the blog page, go to 'Pages' from your admin menu, click 'quick edit' on a post, and you'll see an 'order' box, that's the value that `'orderby' => 'menu_order'` will respect, not your Wordpress navigation menu ordering.

The codex has more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query